# Get rid of warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’ in flex

Tags: c, warnings, bison, flex-lexer, suppress-warnings

I'm trying to get rid of a warning that gcc is throwing when I try to compile my bison and flex files:

```
: In function ‘yy_init_buffer’:
:1675: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘fileno’
```

The reason why I want to do this is because I'm trying to submit an assignment to the class I'm taking but I can only submit the "parser.y" and "scanner.l" files and it gets remotely compiled. The problem is: if there's a warning it gets (for some reason) considered an error and because I have no control over the compiler flags I can't make it disappear. I have seen some questions around the Internet with the same problem, but none of the solutions mentioned worked for me.

The compiler uses se following flags:

```
bison -d -o parser.c parser.y
flex -i -o scanner.c  scanner.l
gcc -std=c99 -pedantic -o test_parser *.c
```

I'm using a Mac OSX so when I compile it doesn't give me any warning, so I'm guessing it's something unique to linux distributions. Here's the header section of each file I have so you have an idea of what I've tried already:

scanner.l

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE 1
//#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
# include "parser.h"
```

parser.y

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int yylex (void);
void yyerror (char const *);
```

Would really appreciate any kind of help here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The traditional answer is, I believe, the one listed in the self-answer: manually declare `fileno`.

My normal practice (and, I think, the most common solution) is to add `-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=700` to my gcc flags. (The 700 is larger than necessary for the declaration of `fileno` but sometimes I use other Posix features.) An alternative would be setting `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`. `_POSIX_SOURCE` is deprecated but it still works.

These need to be compiler options rather than `#define`s in your flex input file because in the generated flex code, `#include <stdio.h>` is inserted before the user-specified prologue, and feature test macros need to be defined before the first use of any standard library header. (See [man feature-test-macros](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/feature_test_macros.7.html) and/or [the Posix specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_02) for more information.)

Since that is not possible in your compilation environment, you'll need to use a workaround. As mentioned, one is to manually declare `fileno` in your prolog.

Another workaround is to avoid the call of `fileno` by specifying `%option never-interactive`, which tells flex to generate a scanner which doesn't attempt to modify its behaviour if the input is a terminal. `%option always-interactive` would also work, but since the scanner will not be used in an interactive environment, it is an unnecessary overhead. These work because `fileno` is only used in order to call `isatty` (which is a Posix function in `unistd.h`) in order to decide whether to activate interactive handling. If you tell flex that the input is always or never interactive, it doesn't require this test. (`fileno` is also needed if you specify the `read` option to avoid use of stdio for input. But you don't and you shouldn't.)

I'm a little surprised that the compilation environment for your course does not include an appropriate feature test macro definition in the compilation step. It should do that, and you can pass my advice on to whoever oversees the build tools.

Answer (score 3):

The problem was solved (momentarily) by adding to the flex file:

```
int fileno(FILE *stream);
```

This is a bad practice but was the only way I could deal with it.

Comment: Bravo for mentioning that it's bad practice.